# How to save the Queryset values to a new database in Django?

Tags: django

I have a Queryset1 with three fields from MyModel1. I will manipulate few fields in views.py which results in a new queryset, Queryset2. Now, I need to save two field values of this Queryset2 to a different database table. How to do this?

Comment: Downvoters, please specify the reason.

Comment: You need to post some code.  What do your two models look like? don't describe them with words.  show your exact models and the models are being queried

Comment: As you read from the question, the intention is not to get my code corrected. I would like to know the Django's approach for such scenario. Hope this clarifies.

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/tutorial01/

Answer (score 0):

You mean you have a `Queryset` with three `Rows`, `Columns` are the fields. If you want to just update a field or more on all three you can use `queryset.update(field=value)` as described here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/models/querysets/#update